# In Tensorflow, when using a prediction i.e. 'print(prediction[0][0])', what are the values [0][0] actually referencing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

Just a quick one, I've been building a neural network for image recognition and I'm pretty much finished. When testing my model's prediction on my test data I am outputting the prediction (obviously) and the tutorial I am following uses the statement `print(prediction[0][0])` (although the difference is this tutorial uses a binary classifier for loss).

I was just wondering what each `[0]` references at the end of the prediction statement (which I have as a variable assigned to `model.predict(testX)`), just so I can play around with my test data easier and know what I'm selecting. I'm sure it's very simple, but I've just spaced it. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hi Popbemo, welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question however is very difficult to answer and does not contribute much in the way that it's currently written. Please, take a moment to review [how to ask great questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that we can help you and you can help improve the knowledge in the site. You are not providing any reference of what you are doing, so we don't really know what you are doing, there are so many things you can do with Tensorflow!

Comment: I did say I was building a neural network for image recognition, but that's pretty much irrelevant. I just forget how to select data with the statement I mentioned in the title.

Comment: What's relevant is the network graph itself, what is this tutorial? Are you using the MNIST tutorial on the TF website? (You probably should if you are beginning with this).

Comment: I can't really say more than *`predicition[0][0]` is some value in a 2-dimensional matrix*. If you are outputting an image, this could be the first pixel, which could be encoded in a variety of ways, depending on how you architected the network. If you are using a supervised learning model, the shape of `predictions` should match your expected target `labels`.

Comment: Yeah I'm following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4K6D_gx2Iw&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfhTox0AjmQ6tvTgMBZBEXN&index=6). Thanks.

Comment: I've got the image to match the label so I now the model is working but I've actually got another problem now if you could maybe help with that. I've passed my entire test set (just over 15000 images) into an array as I did with my training data but it seems the only value I'm getting out is a prediction of 84 which matches the 'Tomato 2' label (working on the moltean/fruits dataset from kaggle). I thought if I passed the entire said it would predict on them all but it seems like only one prediction is coming out here? I'll add my code below...

Comment: https://pastebin.com/5Q2Uac69

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to understand what each `[0]` means, you could always simply print them,
i.e `print(prediction[0])`. Also, you could use [Jupyter Notebooks](https://ipython.org/notebook.html) to fiddle around this stuff.

But, to answer your question, `model.predict` returns a `list` of prediction values, not a single prediction, which is why the first `[0]` is used (I'm guessing you had a a data "set" of a single item), so as to take the first (And only in your case) prediction from the list. Then, the second `[0]` returns the actual prediction value (The only one) from your list of prediction values

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually trying to do a prediction on just over 15000 items. I know this is not practical so I'm not actually trying to predict on all of these but I just want to select random items for my testing. How would I go about this, because as you said the output is only for one prediction? The prediction is correct but I want to test this on other items rather than just the one.